# Transform nested JSON-Array into objects of typescript classes

Tags: json, angular, typescript, spring-boot, http

In the database are the two entities 'person' and 'name'. Between these two entities is a many to many relationship with the two properties 'from' and 'to'.

```
 Person              PersonName                   Name
----------          -------------               -----------
id: number          from: number                 id: number
                    to: number                   firstname: string
                                                 lastname: string
```

The Spring-Boot backend sends a json-array of all persons to the Angular frontend.

A Json Object for a Person looks like this:

```
{
 id: 1, 
 names: [
    {
    from: 1733,
    to: 1735,
    name:  {
            id: 1,
            firstname: John,
            lastname: Doe
           }
    }, ...
]
```

My Angular service looks like this:

```
export class PersonService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getAll(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('//localhost:8080/person')
    };
}
```

I build classes for the entities and the relationship. For example looks the name class like this:

```
export class Name {
    id: number;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
}
```

How can I transform the Json-Array to Objects of the Typescript classes? 
The goal is that the getAll() returns an Observable of Type Person[].

Changing `this.http.get('//localhost:8080/person')` to `this.http.get<Person[]>('//localhost:8080/person')` doesn't return a Person array.

Comment: have you tried using JSON.parse ?

Comment: The best would be if you could change the API to return a List of Person objects. The array response does not look like a single person, because it has an array of names.

Comment: if your person class matches the JSON returned, then that is what it will be. TS classes don't do any mapping for you, if you need that, you ened to write a mapper..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need a mapper (a sample mapper is provided below) in your subscribe. You might need to change the mapper to suit your use case.

e.g.

```
this.personService.getAll().subscribe(result => this.persons = this.mapper(result))
```

```js
const result = {
 id: 1, 
 names: [
    {
    from: 1733,
    to: 1735,
    name:  {
            id: 1,
            firstname: "John",
            lastname: "Doe"
           }
    },
    {
    from: 1735,
    to: 1736,
    name:  {
            id: 2,
            firstname: "Joan",
            lastname: "Smith"
           }
    }
]
}

const mapper = (toMap) => 
  toMap.names.map(p=> p.name)
  
console.log(mapper(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.getAll().subscribe((res) =>{ persons =<Name[]>JSON.parse(res);});
```

you can parse JSON and caste it to Name array

Comment: the angular http client does this for you. never a need to call parse yourself